# 'ShortWriteForm' object has no attribute 'request'

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have a problem about attributeError in django:

```
from postman.forms import BaseWriteForm
from postman.fields import CommaSeparatedUserField
class ShortWriteForm(BaseWriteForm):
    recipients = CommaSeparatedUserField(
        label=(_("Recipients"), _("Recipient")),
        help_text='',
        widget=forms.HiddenInput()
    )
    subject = forms.CharField(
        initial="Kurze Nachricht",
        widget=forms.HiddenInput()
    )
    image = forms.ImageField(
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class': 'hidden'}),
        required=False
    )

    class Meta(BaseWriteForm.Meta):
        fields = ('recipients', 'subject', 'body', 'image')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        recipient = self.cleaned_data["recipients"][0]
        is_succesful = (
            super(ShortWriteForm,self).save(
                recipient=recipient,*args, **kwargs))
        if self.request and self.request.FILES:
            att_form = AttachmentImageForm(
                self.instance, self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
            if att_form.is_valid():
                att_form.save()
        return is_succesful
```

class ShortWriteView(postman_views.riteView):

```
def get_initial(self):
    initial = super(ShortWriteView, self).get_initial()
    recipient = self.kwargs.get('recipients')
    self.recipient = get_object_or_404(User, username=recipient)
    return initial

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ShortWriteView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['recipient'] = self.recipient
    return context
```

And I get this error:

Exception Value:
'ShortWriteForm' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: What is BaseWriteForm? Does it define a `self.request` attribute? Because you're not defining one anywhere here.

Comment: It belongs to postman [django-postman](http://django-postman.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Well that doesn't seem to define a request attribute either, as far as I can see from [the source]( https://bitbucket.org/psam/django-postman/src/95d5e1b67a3e643d0a699eba601e779b307d43f9/postman/forms.py). What makes you think it does?